# JPQL DELETE query: delete entities within a list of another entity

Tags: java, sql, jpa

i try to write a JPQL query, which deletes all entities which are within a collection of another entity.
(Example code, without getter/setter and annotations)

```
class Aa implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String value;
}

@Entity
class A implements Serializable {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @OneToOne
    private Aa aa;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    private List<B> data;
}
@Entity
class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;


    private String value;
}
```

I have tried the following:

```
DELETE FROM B b WHERE b.id IN(SELECT k.id FROM A a JOIN a.data k WHERE a.id = :id)
```

But its end in a foreign key violation exception.
Another approach was

```
DELETE FROM B b WHERE EXISTS(SELECT a FROM A a WHERE a.id = :id)
```

but its end in a foreign key violation too.

However if i execute a sql query on the database directly, like

```
DELETE FROM B WHERE id = <a id number here>
```

then no error occurs...

EntityManager.remove() is not an option because i want to delete a huge amout of data.

I'm thankfully for every answer and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, with the help of Syfors' suggestions i have change the relationship between A and B:

```
class Aa implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String value;
}

@Entity
class A implements Serializable {   
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @JoinColumn(nullable = false)
    @OneToOne
    private Aa aa;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL}, mappedBy = "owner")
    private List<B> data;
}
@Entity
class B implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private A owner;


    private String value;
}
```

I have also found:

> [...]Normally it is best to define the ManyToOne back reference in Java[...]

Source: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany

Now JPA doesn't generate a thrid table for the m:1 relationship and now my JPQL query works fine:

```
DELETE FROM B b WHERE b.id IN(SELECT k.id FROM A a JOIN a.data k WHERE a.id = :id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't add comments since I don't have enough reputation.

You skipped the annotations, which are kind of important, because it would help to know which side, parent, child or maybe something in between them, is in control of the relationship. For example, if parent side is controlling, in some cases it is enough to empty the List on parent side and persist to remove its children. So more code would be helpful.

EDIT 1:

If you are using JPA 2.0 you could add `orphanRemoval="true"` to your `@OneToMany`. Then just get the parent from persistence, do `parent.getData().clear()`, and then do `EntityManager.merge(parent)` OR make children aware of relationship. You are trying to remove children that aren't aware of their parent so I suggest doing so through parent, or making them aware.

Comment: You are right. I have added the annotations in my main post. The parent side is controlling the relation. But i have a huge amount of A objects which store a huge amout of B objects. That's why i using the DELETE statements.

Comment: The problem is, if i call parent.getData(), then all entities in the list are selected (it does no matter if fetch type laze or eager). And i try to prevent this.

Comment: My first approach can be work. I have activated the logging function of jpa and have tested the produced query in squirrel. But, jpa generates a m:n relation with a third table, which triggers the foreign key violation exception. :/